# Media Query overrides background image

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a background image that I want to change when the screen size changes. Apparently, whenever I use the Media Query, it overrides my background image to the color I've input on it. Will that work or both has to image? Thank you.

```
#home {
padding-top: 35px;
background-image: url("../images/homebg.jpg");
background-size: cover;
height: 100vh;
width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 480px) {
#home {
    background: #fcb595;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not the media query that 'overwrites' your previously made styles, it's the fact that you are using the short-hand `background` style.

In most cases, this overwrites any previously set `background-*` styles, which includes your `background-image` style.

Instead, how about:

```css
@media (min-width: 480px) {
    #home {
        background-color: #fcb595;
    }
}
```

Note: Unless you have some transparent portions of your background image, this style is redundant, since the background image will cover the background colour anyway.

Comment: i don't think answer is right ... because his code is perfect . i think , he is confused about `max-width` and `min-width`.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question answer is it will work and it is not mandatory that both have to be an image .

Your code is working perfectly. But I think you are confused about `max-width` and `min-width`. Your code is working nice. [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pw2sjj3f/1/)

Html :

```
<div id= "home">

</div>
```

Css:

```
#home {
padding-top: 35px;
background-image: url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTupAbxBl02rU1nM9ZA0OLBlsDKmoAoOlhCfUdP0XDeFLj8q1Ec");
background-size: cover;
height: 100vh;
width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 480px) {
#home {
    background: #fcb595;
}
}
```